# multi login for online shopping

Tags: php, mysql

```
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password= md5($_POST['password']);
if (empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true) {


$errors='Please fill both of the fields:';

  }

else
{

$select= mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user  "); 

$login= mysqli_fetch_array($select);

if($login['email'] ==$email && $login['password'] == $password && 

$login['user_type']== 'Admin'){

      $_SESSION['email']=$email;

header('location:Admin/index.php');  


  }


 else {


      echo  $_SESSION['email']=$email;

      header('location:index.php');

}

  $errors='You are not admin please enter valid email and password'; 

  }





        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" />
                            <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" />
                            <span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> 
                                Keep me signed in
                            </span>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="login">Login</button>
                        </form>
```

*

> This code is used for admin and user login panels but its only work on admin

side and not on user side this is use for online shopping system where is the

user id or email is necessary for placing orders
its also not show session variable on user side
*

Comment: Honestly, there are *a lot* of things wrong here.  But for starters... (1) You only ever check the first record in the `user` table.  Surely there are more users?  (2) You only check if the login is correct *and* the user is an admin.  For any other case (such as an incorrect login) you assume they are a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

in else part use the following condition to check whether person trying to login is `Admin / user` .

```
        else {
    if($login['email'] ==$email && $login['password'] == $password && 

$login['user_type']== 'user'){

      $_SESSION['email']=$email;

header('location:index.php');

    }
```

in user type i just mentioned it as `user(as an example)`. You need to type exact user type in db,which you are using.